# Problem regarding plus-minus in logarithm.

Tags: logarithms

In the equation below,

> Solve for $x$: $\log\left(x^2\right)=4$

Here, I think that the  answer is going to be $100$ and $-100$. Because if we insert $-100$, $x^2$ is still positive and thereby, it doesn't violate the rule that we can only insert positive values in logarithm.

But another counter point I have is that, we can write the expression as,

2log(x)=4

Or, log(x)=2

Or, x=10^2

In this way, I get the only positive value. Which one of them is correct? And if process 1 is, what are the flaws in the second?

Comment: This equation has two solutions.

Comment: @TheSilverDove, then why doesn't process 2 also give 2 solutions? (With plus minus)

Comment: Because the equality $\log(x^2) = 2 \log(x)$ is not correct for all $x$. The correct equality for all real $x$ is $\log(x^2) = 2 \log(|x|)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that $\ \log\left(x^2\right) = 2\log(x)\ $ **if and only if** $\ x > 0.$

If $x < 0$ then $\log\left(x^2\right)$ is defined but $2\log(x)$ is not, so the equation is false.

The method using the equation $\log\left(x^2\right) = 2\log(x)$ will find a positive solution if one exists.
But if there is a negative solution, that method cannot find it.

A more general statement is
$$ \log\left(x^2\right) = 2\log\left(\lvert x\rvert\right), $$
which is true whenever $x \neq 0.$
Using that fact, you can find both solutions.

Comment: So, to be clear, log(x^n) = nlog(।x।) if n is even and, if n is an odd number, it is log(x^n)= nlog(x). Ami I right?

Comment: Yes. It is because $x^n = \lvert x\rvert^n$ when $n$ is an even integer. And you are correct, the equation with the absolute value is wrong if $n$ is odd, because then $x^n$ has the same sign as $x.$

Answer (score 3):

If it's $\log_{10}$, use the definition before the first step, because the argument of $\log$ is postive, and then solve for $x$:
$$
x^2 = 10^4\\
(x-100)(x+100)=0
$$

Comment: That what it's all about.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following two properties:

$u=\log_b(v)$ if and only if $v=b^u$

$u^2=a$ if and only if $u=\sqrt{a}$ or $u=-\sqrt{a}$